# website transfer from folder in public_html to public_html caused errors

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, transfer

I just transferred my website from example.com/newsite to example.com by moving the folder where everything was stored (newsite) into my public_html to make it the root domain. Now I am receiving multiple issues on my error_log and the website is loading very very slowly. The error log is telling me things like:

> PHP Warning:  current() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /home3/example/public_html/**newsite**/wp-content/plugins/lezada-addons/includes/templates/lezada_brands_grid.php on line 79

I was thinking the urls containing example.com/newsite should be rewritten via .htaccess

Will this resolve the problem? If so what would the rewrite code be? I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com\newsite$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this isn't working and the website is down!

Comment: Your question is probably more suited for [webmasters.se]. Note that HTTP_HOST is just an hostname, not a URL, and URLs uses `/` not \ anyway. Also, about the "urgently" part, please have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: _“I was thinking the urls containing example.com/newsite should be rewritten via .htaccess”_ - why? The error message has nothing to do with URLs. What it mentions, is a _file system_ path. And if that still says `/home3/example/public_html/newsite/`, then you probably didn’t move everything from `newsite` to the `public_html` as you think you did?